# Laravel-Stripe-webhooks everything working but handle code not reached

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-6

I have a Laravel 6 app and am moving form Stripe legacy client-side checkout to their current server-side checkout. Everything works fine except my webhook handle code, it looks like it's not run. I'm using the Spatie `laravel-stripe-webhooks` package for this, but it's not working, at least the last important piece where I hand the Stripe payload back to my code for client processing. I've literally spent the last few days going through this, testing everything and searching for answers, to no avail.

Using the Stripe CLI I can test my endpoint, and watch the transaction steps and the 200 responses. The Stripe dashboard also records complete and error free transactions. I'm not getting any errors on either end at this stage, but placing log messages in the job handler indicates that the code is not reached.

[image: Stripe CLI]

Stripe secret/API keys are good and working. Charges are being processed on the Stripe end, no issues there. Simply need to get the payload back from Stripe to complete the process.

Here's my endpoint in `\config\stripe-webhooks.php`.

```
<?php

return [

    'signing_secret' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'),

    'jobs' => [
        'invoice_payment_succeeded' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\InvoicePaymentSucceededJob::class,
        "payment_intent_succeeded" => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\PaymentIntentSucceeded::class,
    ],
    'model' => \Spatie\StripeWebhooks\ProcessStripeWebhookJob::class,
];
```

Here's my `\App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\PaymentIntentSucceeded.php` job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use IlluminateSupportFacadesLog;

class PaymentIntentSucceeded implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

     /** @var \Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall */
     public $webhookCall;
     

    public function __construct(WebhookCall $webhookCall)
    {
        
        $this->webhookCall = $webhookCall;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("Job Started");

        $charge = $this->webhookCall->payload['data']['object'];

        Log::info("Job Ended");
    }
}
```

My logging is working fine as I can log events from elsewhere, but the above log calls are not being reached.

This is baffling, as it should work according to everything I've read. Any and all suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Anyone........?(bump)

Comment: Anybody out there with any Laravel-stripe-webhooks experience? I feel like I'm missing something crucial, but 2 months of searching later and I've gotten nowhere

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue:
Following command solves my issue:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan queue:clear
```

You could also try `php artisan queue:listen` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your Webhook handler class is by default extending **ShouldQueue** which your payload will be handled depend in your current **QUEUE_CONNECTION** in .env file and it might be database

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

so if you need your current payload to be processed without waiting to be dispatch you can switch to

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

if you wouldn't change **QUEUE_CONNECTION** because you are using different approach in other staff and you want this webhook connection only to be sync, just change **$connection** var

```
class ProcessWebhookJob extends SpatieProcessWebhookJob
{
    public $connection = 'sync';
 }
```